# Adding options to an html select element

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have the following select element in my html file:

```
<select id="usr-slct">
</select>
```

to which I am trying to add some options using javascript in a script tag just before the end of the document's body. Like this:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("usr-slct");
var newoption = document.createElement("option").text="User1";
selector.add(newoption);
```

I would like to know why this code does not make my page display the new option in the select and how can I make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.createElement("option").text="User1"` returns `"User1"`, the result of the assignment, not a `HTMLOptionElement`. You should code:

```
var newoption = document.createElement("option");
newoption.text = "User1";
selector.add(newoption);
```

**edit**: OP is using `.add()` method for adding an `option` to the `select` element. [`HTMLSelectElement` object does have `.add()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` element has an 'options' property, which is an array. You can create new options by using:

`selector.options[selector.options.length] = new Option('text1', 'value1');`

This would add a new Option, with text of `text1` and value of `value1`, to the end of the selector's options array which would return the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're doing this:

```
var newoption = document.createElement("option").text = "User1";
```

which is two times wrong:

- First of all, in Javascript, an assignment returns the assigned value, so assigning `"User1"` to the text property of the newly created option results in your variable holding the string `"User1"`, not the element; you have to first create the element and then change its text.
- Secondly, you should change the `textContent` property, not the `text` property, which doesn't mean anything to the DOM.

Here's the correct code:

```
var selector = document.getElementById("usr-slct");
var newoption = document.createElement("option");

newoption.textContent = "User1";
selector.add(newoption);
```